# How to resolve this java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported in Android L?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, toolbar

i am try on multiple item click to share item using `MultiChoiceModeListener` i got `FATAL EXCEPTION` in onCreateActionMode method
 i have already using `AppCompat v21.0.2`, before L update this code work perfectly in `AppCompat v19`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mActionMode = mode;
    nr = 0;
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item_menu_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem
        .getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider
        .setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(PlanetFragment.this);

    return true;
}
```

Exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider()
    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setActionProvider(MenuItemImpl.java:639)
    at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:445)
    at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addSubMenuItem(MenuInflater.java:457)
    at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:186)
    at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:110)
    at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:109)
    at com.mydata.PlanetFragment$GetDataAsyncTask$1.onCreateActionMode(PlanetFragment.java:252)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onCreateActionMode(AbsListView.java:6203)
    at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:154)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1297)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.startSupportActionModeFromWindow(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:648)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.startActionMode(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:99)
    at android.support.v7.widget.WindowCallbackWrapper.startActionMode(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
    at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.startActionMode(ToolbarActionBar.java:206)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.startSupportActionMode(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:581)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateHC.startActionModeForChild(ActionBarActivityDelegateHC.java:62)
    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout.startActionModeForChild(NativeActionModeAwareLayout.java:44)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:677)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:677)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:677)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:677)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:677)
    at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:4347)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2874)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2834)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:756)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:572)
    at miui.dexspy.DexspyInstaller.main(DexspyInstaller.java:171)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is old question, but I will post my solution, maybe someone will find it usable.

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateActionMode");

            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_select_menu, menu);
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
            mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
            MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(item, mShareActionProvider);

            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();
```

to

```
mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
```